# Exibir conteúdo de duas tabelas em uma sanfona referente ao seu ID

Tags: php

Tenho duas tabelas:

- a primeira é `temporadas`, que seguram apenas o nome da temporada. Exemplo: `Primeira Temporada`, `Segunda Temporada`, etc.
- tenho outra tabela que segura cada episódio referente a sua temporada.

Os episódios são exibidos em um efeito sanfona, o nome `Primeira Temporada` é o link do efeito sanfona, aí tenho a div `conteudo` que vai segurar os `episodios` referentes a cada temporada.

O que estou com dificuldade é em exibir cada episódio em sua temporada no efeito sanfona.

> Eu não passo o `id_temporada` na URL

```
<?php   
$url = explode("/",$_GET['url'],-1);
$url = $url[1];
if(isset($_GET['id_serie'])){
    $id_serie = $_GET['id_serie'];
}
$temporada = "SELECT * FROM temporadas WHERE id_serie = '$url' AND audio = 'Dublado'";
$temporadaShow = mysqli_query($conn,$temporada);
while($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($temporadaShow)){  
?>
    <div class="caixa align_left">
    <!-- Exibo o nome da temporada -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="titulo" id="<?php echo $show['id_temporada'];?>">
         <?php echo $show['temporada_serie'];?>
    </a>
    <!-- div que vai segurar os episodio no meu efeito sanfona -->
    <div class="conteudo hide" id="<?php echo $show['id_temporada'];?>">    
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['id_temporada'])){
                $id_temporada = $_GET['id_temporada'];
            }
            $episodio = "SELECT * FROM episodios WHERE id_temporada = '$id_temporada' AND audio = 'Dublado'";
            $episodioShow = mysqli_query($conn,$episodio);
            while($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($episodioShow)){
                 echo "aqui eu exibiria o episodio";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Apaguei meu comentário já que resolveu aquele.

Comment: Por que você não usa o id_serie na sua consulta?

Comment: @VWE o `id_serie` é auto increment, oque corresponde a temporada é o `id_temporada`, se você quiser posso colocar as estruturas das minha tabelas